# Django : MultiValueDictKeyError at /app/logout/ when using HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: python, django, redirect, logout

I've been trying to redirect a user to main when the user logs out using Django built logout method. However, it keeps sending me an error message like this. Which part is wrong?

error message :

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /blog/logout/   "'path'"
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout 

@login_required
def logout(request):
    logout(request)

    return HttpResponseRedirect('blog/login.html')
```

urls.py

```
 url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
 url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, name='logout'),
```

EDIT 01 
I tried to find path variable but couldn't find it.
Also, I changed logout method code.

```
@login_required
def logout(request):
   logout(request)

   return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/login/')
```

This is login in views.py

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                items = Article.objects.filter(is_visible=True)
                request.session['username']=username
                return render(request, 'blog/home.html', {'items': items})
            else:
                return render(request, 'blog/login.html', {'error_message': 'This account has been locked'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'blog/login.html', {'error_message': 'invaild login'})
    return render(request, 'blog/login.html')
```

and I don't know if this is relevant but I added this line in the settings.py

```
#added for login authentification
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi  you mean return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/login/') like this?

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi It throws error like 'MultiValueDictKeyError at /blog/logout/
"'path'"  ,  Is this caused by url?

Comment: Then show me the exact view of logout with the whole code. And the exact directory structure. Alos tell me what is this "path" variable and where  is it placed in the code??

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi I updated. I tried to find path variable from views.py but couldn't find it..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135826/discussion-between-prakhar-trivedi-and-camila).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line :

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('blog/login.html')
```

**HttpResponseRedirect** needs a **URL path** not the location/path of a template, I think what you need is :

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth import logout as django_logout 

@login_required
def logout(request):
    django_logout(request)

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/login/')
```

And also change these lines of login view :

```
username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']
```

TO :

```
username = request.POST.get('username') 
password = request.POST.get('password')
```